# Strange behaviour in a mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite rule to remove the .php extension from my pages. Its pretty much the same as every sample I have seen for the technique and I have tried variations with the same result.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

It works, but I have this strange anomaly that I just cannot understand.

All my php files are stored in the root folder, I have no sub-folders. If I try a url with a subfolder, I get a 404 page as expected.

However, if I use a php script name as the folder I get a 500 Internal server error.

For example, I have a script called "logout.php"

http://example.com/eifiefj/ppp  gives 404 page

http://example.com/logout/ppp gives 500 error  ???????????????????

The Apache error logs says...

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
r->uri = /logout/ppp.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp.php.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp.php.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp.php.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp.php.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp.php.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp.php.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp.php
redirected from r->uri = /logout/ppp
headers: ap_headers_error_filter()
```

This is more of a "I want to know why its happening" issue. I just cannot see why it wants to keep adding the .php, surely it should be failing the last RewriteCond?

I would be interested to know if this behaviour happens to everyone else who uses the removing extension technique.

As suggested the RewriteLog...

```
add path info postfix: /var/www/public/logout -> /var/www/public/logout/ppp
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/public/logout/ppp -> logout/ppp
applying pattern '^(.+)$' to uri 'logout/ppp'
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/public/logout' pattern='!-f' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/public/logout' pattern='!-d' => matched
RewriteCond: input='/var/www/public/logout.php' pattern='-f' => matched
rewrite 'logout/pod' -> 'logout/ppp.php'
add per-dir prefix: logout/ppp.php -> /var/www/public/logout/ppp.php
strip document_root prefix: /var/www/public/logout/ppp.php -> /logout/ppp.php
internal redirect with /logout/ppp.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]

nb The log then basically repeats itself adding .php to the end of the filename
```

It seems that REQUEST_FILENAME contains "/var/www/public/logout" and I can see that adding the php extension will match the final rule.  Surely the REQUEST_FILENAME should be "/var/www/public/logout/ppp" ? Why am I losing the /ppp ?

Comment: Enable the RewriteLog, then you can see what actually happens during the rewriting process.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the RewriteLog. It appears that my parameter is picking up incorrect information, or the parameter is generally misunderstood! (The code is sourced from many examples on the web).

Comment: REQUEST_FILENAME is defined in docs as _“The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the request”_ – most likely you have [Options MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#options) enabled, that will make Apache serve the file `logout.php` even if only `logout` is requested.

Comment: I have the line "Options None +FollowSymLinks" which I think discounts MultiView as the cause. * I do have a working solution which I put in the answer section, but it would be nice to find the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not actually answering the question of why the RewriteCond is failing, I have found a set of rules which actually overcomes the folder/script problem. I reproduce it here to help anyone seeking a functional script.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php
```

This RewriteRule will only be applied to files whose name does not contain a full stop, ie files without an extension.